# jQuery show hide and active class in one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, hide, show

I have this code and I want to add active class to button `.loginhead` (to remove and add class when click and when content show and hide). How I can do that?

```
$(".top .login").hide('', function () {
    $('.loginhead').removeClass("active");  
});

$(".loginhead").show();

$('.loginhead').click(function () {
    $(".top .login").slideToggle();
    $('.loginhead').addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `toggleClass()`. If I'm understanding you right. Here's a link to documentation: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

```
$('.loginhead').toggleClass("active");
```

Comment: Thanks, taht's what i search! If the system can accept you're answer than i accept it :)

Comment: it takes a few minutes to be able to accept an answer. glad to help.